# Facebook - full page overlay

Tags: css, facebook

I recently saw something like this,

[image]
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/812/overlayexample.jpg/

It is a requests dialog that covers the whole Facebook site. I appreciate any ideas how to accomplish this overlay?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the css for the iFrame you'll see:

```
.generic_dialog {
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    outline: medium none;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 250;
}

.generic_dialog_popup {
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    padding-left:60px;
    padding-right:60px;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:200;
}

#generic_dialog_overlay {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100%;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

They seem to be giving the desire effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved by two different `div`'s.

First you will need an 'overlay' div that has a `width` and `height` of `100%` and a `position` of `fixed`, also a high `z-index`. This overlay will need a background image with transparency or opacity filters to achieve the overlay effect.

Then you have the `div` that contains the actual dialog, you will need to position this with css and/or javascript depending on the contents.